# How to read json data from a website in php?

Tags: php, json

I have this website what gives me json data,

https://httpbin.org/ip

How do I get it and read it in php?

Comment: What have you tried? `file_get_contents` and `json_decode` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should must work.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("https://httpbin.org/ip"); 
print_r($data );
```

Comment: After that you can convert it to json or parse it in any type.